# Missing appcfg.py for app-engine deployment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I have inherited an app-engine project.

I try to deploy from my dev machine:

`appcfg.py --oauth2 update PATH`

I have installed app-engine SDK but I cannot find `appcfg.py`

I have googled and it seems like `appcfg.py` is no longer in use?

How should I deploy otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct `appcfg.py` is no longer used to deploy.

Instead you should use the gcloud cli instead:

```
gcloud app deploy --project project-id --version version-number
```

See the reference documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

Also, make sure you have an updated `app.yaml` in your project.

Comment: how should i update `app.yaml`? the link in the answer doesn't say

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the app-engine SDK for JAVA

I had to install app-engine SDK for python

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/uploadinganapp